# CAS proxy ticket validation time and number of time it can be used

Tags: java, spring, grails, cas

Is there any way to increase the number of times a proxy ticket can be used, when using the CAS server. Also, is there any way to increase the time before a ticket expires. I know about the **ticketExpirationPolicies.xml** file in CAS and I have tried changing the file as follows

```
<bean id="serviceTicketExpirationPolicy" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.support.MultiTimeUseOrTimeoutExpirationPolicy">
        <!-- This argument is the number of times that a ticket can be used before its considered expired. -->
        <constructor-arg
            index="0"
            value="10" />

        <!-- This argument is the time a ticket can exist before its considered expired.  -->
        <constructor-arg
            index="1"
            value="7200000" />
    </bean>
```

But this does not let me use the proxy ticket again. I get the message  So, is there any other way to do it or am I doinig something wrong.

Thanks

Comment: This was the message I was talking about. Sorry I missed it <ServiceTicket [ST-11-kuKoogfvkCQi3pCLFyGL-cas] has expired.>

Comment: What is it on the other side? Verimatrix?

Comment: There are two grails-app..A and B where app A proxies app B.